# How to reduce digits of a number in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a "CSV" file with four columns:

```
rep   par  comm    value
USA   GER  60705    100
USA   GER  607034   200
GER   US   607094   300
US    UK   60709    340
```

I intend to reduce the values for comm column and change them to four digits numbers as follows:

```
rep   par  comm    value
USA   GER  6070     100
USA   GER  6070     200
GER   US   6070     300
US    UK   6070     340
```

For doing this, I have written following code:

```
infile=csv.reader(open("filepath"))
wfile=open("newfilpath", "wb")
writer=csv.writer(wfile, delimiter=",")
writer.writerow(["rep","par","comm","value"])
infile.next()
for row in infile:
    comm=row[2]
    hs4=comm[0:4]
    writer.writerow([row[0],row[1],hs4,row[3]])
wfile.close()
```

But for numbers like 60705 and 60709 (which are 5 digits), I get 607 not 6070.
Update: I realized that Python add Zero to the numbers with 5 digits and 60705 becomes 060705 as an example. I do not know how to fix this problem. Here is a my output for the real data:

```
'ALB,DNK,880390,11678\n'
'ALB,FIN,961420,10377\n'
'ALB,FRA,030741,10857\n'
'ALB,FRA,030749,4300\n'
'ALB,FRA,091050,14861\n'
'ALB,FRA,121190,1049561\n'
'ALB,FRA,130219,7291\n'
```

All the data that starts with zero are 5 digits in fact and Python adds zero automatically to the data.

Comment: Well, Ive tested your loop on a two dimensional array I put together of your data, there is nothing wrong with that part of the code. My output is as expected. Would you mind posting an exact copy of your csv-file's content?

And how about some print statements at different places in your code, to pinpoint even more precisely where the error is happening?

Comment: Try printing `hs4` before slicing it, there may be a character at the start that gets ignored later.

Comment: It works for me, too. I would say there is something in your .csv that is not exactly like you posted.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the first several lines of your csv file.  The way you describe it, there are no commas.  That doesn't make sense

Comment: I suspect that there are invisible chars (or something) messing things up. Can you post the `repr()` of your data into the question? Eg, `with open("filepath") as f:` `for row in f:` `print(repr(row))` (with proper indenting).

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, you are right, When I checked my data using your command, I can see Python add Zero into the numbers with 5 digits and the number 60705 becomes 060705, Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Please paste the output of that command block (in a code block) into your question. We _need_ to see it to help you properly.

Comment: It will help a lot to open the file in a text editor and copy/paste into your question. That way we can see the internal formatting.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon: The `repr()` output would be even better if the data contains invisible chars.

Comment: @PM2Ring I pasted my output. As you can see, zeros have been added to the data.

Comment: @cnluzon I realized that Python adds zeros to the 5 digits numbers automatically but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon unfortunately the size of the data is about 43.1 MB and it's too large.

Comment: Even a couple of lines would help. Anyway, I've updated my answer to strip the leading zeros.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon great, it works perfectly. thank you so muchhh

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that you have a space in front of the 6. You can try the `.strip()` method to get rid of it. I've also modified your code slightly here:

EDIT : now removes leading zeros

```
import csv

with open("filepath") as ifile, open("newfilpath", "wb") as wfile:
    infile = csv.reader(ifile)
    writer = csv.writer(wfile)
    writer.writerow(next(infile))
    for row in infile:
        row[2] = row[2].strip().lstrip('0')[:4]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Always good practice to strip the value.  The op should actually cut and paste the csv file, since what is shown doesn't have any commas in it to separate

Comment: You are right because when I copy/paste a part of my file to another csv file, the problem is not seen anymore. Anyway, your code did not fix my problem but thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying following method by using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print df
t=(df['comm']).astype(str)
for i in t:
    print i[:4]
```

Output:

```
   rep  par    comm  value
0  USA  GER   60705    100
1  USA  GER  607034    200
2  GER   US  607094    300
3   US   UK   60709    340
6070
6070
6070
6070
```

Comment: Yes, it's a better idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a slightly modified code to read the CSV file, I get:

```
import csv

infile=csv.reader(open("filepath"), delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
wfile=open("newfilpath", "wb")
writer=csv.writer(wfile, delimiter=",")
writer.writerow(["rep","par","comm","value"])
infile.next()
for row in infile:
    print row
    comm=row[2]
    hs4=comm[0:4]
    writer.writerow([row[0],row[1],hs4,row[3]])


wfile.close()}
```

With the input:

```
rep   par  comm    value
USA   GER  60705    100
USA   GER  607034   200
GER   US   607094   300
US    UK   60709    340
```

Using your code, I get an output of:

```
rep,par,comm,value
USA,GER,6070,100
USA,GER,6070,200
GER,US,6070,300
US,UK,6070,340
```

The only thing I can think of is changing the delimiter settings or skipinitialspace when you read in your CSV file.